# How to restart a forEach() loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following loop which goes through the characters of each array element, and stops.

```
var container = $("#myid")
container.shuffleNames();
const names = ["", "john", "rita", "katsigaros", "jonathan", "peepee"];

names.forEach((i, t) => {
        (function(index, text) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                container.shuffleNames({
                    "text": text
                });
            }, index * 3000);
        })(t, i);
});
```

How can I make it to kick back from the beginning when looping ends and restart for infinity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interval that runs forever and just access the next element in `names` each time, bu incrementing a variable that stores the index of the current name and using `%` to reset it back to 0 when it exceeds the length of the array:

```
let index = 0;
setInterval( ( ) => {
  container.shuffleNames({
    "text": names[ index = (index + 1) % names.length ]
  });
}, 3000 );
```

Comment: it almost does the job, the only flaw it has is that while it restarts, it accesses again the last element of the array "peepee" and then goes to continue from first element. It goes `.... last => (restarts) last -> first -> second -> n`

Comment: considering that first array element is empty " ", probably needs some modification